Is there an insert - Place in Cell function in PhpSpreadsheet?
I am trying to insert an image inside a cell of an Microsoft Excel document using phpSpreadSheet
$drawing->setName('Image');
$drawing->setDescription('Image');
$drawing->setPath($pathFile);
$drawing->setCoordinates('I' . $lastCount);
//$drawing->setOffsetX(10);
//$drawing->setOffsetY(10);
$drawing->setWidth(80);
$drawing->setHeight(80);
$drawing->setWorksheet($spreadSheet->getActiveSheet());

I am using this to insert it but it adds it on top of the cell and not inside like Excel's "Insert - Place in Cell" functionality.
Does anyone know if this functionality exists in PhpSpreadsheet?
